# Math.Random() Java. Stay Constant

Tags: java, math, bluej

I'm trying to make a program/game where the user has to guess a number 1-100.  I am aware of how to use the random class, but I have to use Math.Random for this (school project).  The issue I'm having is that I can't make the number stay the same across multiple guesses.  A random number is generated, but it changes on every guess, rendering it pointless.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Guess implements ActionListener
{
JFrame f;
Container c;
JPanel p;
JTextField x;
JLabel title, out;
JButton guess;
int outp, num;

public Guess()
{
    f = new JFrame("Guess a Number!");
    f.setSize(230,190);
    c = f.getContentPane();
    p = new JPanel();
    title = new JLabel("Guess a Number (1-10):");
    x = new JTextField(10);
    guess = new JButton("Guess");
    guess.addActionListener(this);
    out = new JLabel("");
    p.add(title);
    p.add(x);
    p.add(out);
    p.add(guess);
    c.add(p);
    f.show();
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getSource() == guess)
{
    outp = (int)((Math.random() * 100 + 1));
    int numb = Integer.parseInt(x.getText());
    if(numb > outp)
    {
        out.setText("Number is Lower");
    }
    if(numb < outp)
    {
        out.setText("Number is Higher");
    }
    if(numb == outp)
    {
        out.setText("Correct!");
    }
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your probelem is that you are regenerating a new random number each time they guess. Simply put

```
outp = (int)((Math.random() * 100 + 1));
```

Into the constructor and you'll be set.